# Comparing all the characters beetween two strings(even if they contain numbers)in java

Tags: java

Ok so I currently have a String array which contains keycodes, and i want to check if the first element shares common specifications with the second , e.g. [012] has similar elements with [123]. I currently loop through the length of the first element, and then loop through the length of the second element, and compare those two like this:
If(A[1].charAt(j) == A[2].charAt[i]) c++; c is a counter to show how many 
common elements the keycodes have. Here is the method i created

```
   static boolean hasSimilarity(String[] A, int K, int i){
        int c = 0;
        for(int j = 0;j<K;j++){                 
            for(int m = j;m<K;m++){
                if(A[i].charAt(j) == A[i+1].charAt(m)) c++;
            }
        }
        return c != 0;
    }
```

And here is the execution of it in the Main class:

```
 int max = -1;
 findSimilar FS = new findSimilar();
 for (int i = 0; i < sum.length -1; i++) {
    boolean hasSimilar = FS.hasSimilarity(key,K,i);
    if (!hasSimilar) {
       int summ = sum[i] + sum[i + 1];
       System.out.println(summ);
       if (summ > max) {
          max = summ;
       }
    }
 }
```

When i run this, i get a java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException out of range: 0 . What am I doing wrong? Is there any better way to compare two keycodes in order to find similarities beetween them?

Comment: can add sample of strings for test ?

Comment: Also add more of the code please, like what is `sum`, `key`, `K`, and `FS`. From your code it appears the problem is on both `i+1`, in `A[i+1]` and `sum[i + 1]` the loop is already in the final element and you are trying to get the next, create an `IF'`to stop at list.size - 2.

Comment: Typical java style has  variables starting with a lower case letter.

Comment: Yes. Please follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names are written in camelCase, and class names in PascalCase. So `A` and `K` should be `a` and `k` respectively, `FS` should be `fs`, and `findSimilar` should be `FindSimilar`. And it's better to use more descriptive variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException out of range: 0

Can only occur if one of your strings is the blank string `""`.

You are attempting to get `charAt(0)` when there is no char `0` (ie first char).

——-

You would avoid this problem, and have a far more efficient algorithm, if you first collected the counts of each character then compared those, which would have time complexity O(n), whereas your algorithm is O(n<sup>2</sup>) (albeit that it seems your `n` - the length of your inputs - is small).